# getting NPM error while generating JHipster project

Tags: spring, npm, nodes, npm-install, node-modules

Overview of the issue
I am getting NPM error while creating a simple project using JHipster or Yo Jhipster command

Related issues
Yes, I have checked for a similar issue but didn't find any issue similar to this with NPM.

Suggest a Fix
I think dependencies are available in staging in my case but the project is not getting its path properly.

JHipster Version(s)
5.7.2

JHipster configuration
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster: info
INFO! Options: from-cli: true
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

JHipster configuration, a .yo-rc.json file generated in the root folder

```
.yo-rc.json file
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.test"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.7.2",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "JhipsterFirstApp",
    "packageName": "com.test",
    "packageFolder": "com/test",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "bXktc2VjcmV0LXRva2VuLXRvLWNoYW5nZS1pbi1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLWFuZC10by1rZWVwLWluLWEtc2VjdXJlLXBsYWNl",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

JDL for the Entity configuration(s) entityName.json files generated in the .jhipster directory
JDL entity definitions
Environment and Tools
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

git version 2.16.1.windows.4

node: v10.15.0

npm: 6.5.0

yeoman: 2.0.5

yarn: 1.12.3

INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!

Entity configuration(s) entityName.json files generated in the .jhipster directory
I am not sure, I think its related to NPM dependencies.

Browsers and Operating System

[I am getting this as error msg on cmd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuT96.png)

Comment: Seems like your NPM install step failed. Doesn't look like a JHipster issue. It's mostly an environment issue with your setup. Try running NPM install manually on the project you created and work from the error you receive.

Comment: To be precise its an NPM issue with your setup. May be you need to upgrade your Node and NPM versions

Comment: I installed the latest version of node without any failure during installation and tried to install node dependencies manually by "npm install" but still I am getting the same issue. @Deepu